# Show that the product of the divisors of an even perfect number is $n^p$.

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

Let $n=(2^{p-1})\cdot(2^p-1)$ where n is an even prefect number and p is prime.

I know the divisors are $1, 2, 2^2, 2^3, ..., 2^{p-1}, 2^p-1$, and $n$.

I get $(2^{(1/2)p(p-1)}\cdot ((2^p)-1)\cdot(2^{p-1} \cdot(2^p-1))$ but I can't turn it into $n^p$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n = 2^{p-1} (2^p - 1)$ denote an *even perfect number*.

Let $T(n)$ denote the *product of divisors* of $n$.

Then, in general, we have the formula
$$T(n) = n^{d(n)/2}$$
where $d(n)$ is the *number of divisors* of $n$.

Let us use the formula for the number of divisors of $n$, $d(n)$:

Since $n = 2^{p-1} (2^p - 1)$, then
$$d(n) = (1+1)((p - 1) + 1) = 2p.$$

Therefore, the product of divisors of $n$, is given by:
$$T(n) = n^{d(n)/2} = n^{2p/2} = n^p.$$

---

Reference:

[On the product of divisors of a positive integer - Tibor Šalát and Jana Tomanová, Mathematica Slovaca (2002) Volume: 52, Issue: 3, page 271-287](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/129329/MathSlov_52-2002-3_3.pdf)